# Datatable layout gets messed up with scrollX

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have 4 tables on my site. Only 1 is displayed at a time. I have a wrapper around eaech of the tables that get hidden and shown over javascript. When I toggle between them it completly messes up the layout.
This issue appeared after I set the Scrollx to true, which is necessary for the application. It also creates a margin between the header and tablebody.
This is a table code:

```
            <div style="display:none;" id="longtimeTableWrapper" class="col-12 tableWrapper ">
            <table id="longtimeTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered reservationTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Kennzeichen
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Sichtausweis
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Datum von
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Datum bis
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Grund
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Bemerkung
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            2. Kennzeichen
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Betrag
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Adresse
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Telefon
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Areal
                        </th>
                        <th class="th-sm">
                            Erfasser
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{
                        foreach (var longtimeReservation in Model.ReservationsVM.LongtimeParkingReservations)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CarMark</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.GivenName @longtimeReservation.SurName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.BadgeNumber</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                                <td>Grund</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.Area.AreaName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CreatedByNavigation.UserName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CreatedByNavigation.UserName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CreatedByNavigation.UserName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CreatedByNavigation.UserName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CreatedByNavigation.UserName</td>
                                <td>@longtimeReservation.CreatedByNavigation.UserName</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a id="PdfExport" class="m-1  "> <i class=" rgba-red-slight z-depth-1 red-text p-2 rounded fa-1x fas fa-file-pdf "></i></a>
                                    <a id="PdfExport" class="m-1   "> <i class=" rgba-red-slight z-depth-1 red-text p-2 rounded fa-1x fas fa-file-pdf "></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
```

This is the result

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do share your Datatables init with the options or update this fiddle to reproduce your problem and create a SO snippet https://jsfiddle.net/ud2tbr3x/

Comment: I have a default for all datatables where I set the following:

$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "scrollX": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true});

And also:
        $('#longtimeTable').DataTable();

Comment: I see no problem here or I can't seem to be able to reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/49gu1spt/ could you please, try and reproduce? Or I can't help

Comment: I think the issue is that I hide and show them because thats what causes the issue im pretty sure. I don't know how to fix it tho

Comment: Then create a full working snippet of your problem!! :) I can't guess, and I can't try and fix what I can't see